# WCF Call, slow on Internal Funcions, but quick when calling functions directly

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, performance, wcf

I have a self hosted WCF service, using basic http binding. I am finding that calls made to the wcf service, accessing functions exposed by the WCF, take much much longer to complete (internally) than when using the functions directly (from the wcf service).

So to clarify, I am not talking about taking longer "over" the wcf call. Once the internal exposed functions behind the WCF are run, they, in their own processing, take much longer to do their work and return something back to the wcf service, for sending to the client, than when I access those same functions directly from a form in my hosted wcf app.

I have added extensive logging, logging start and stop time for all functions, and it seems to be consistent. The same functions, when activated through WCF, seems as if they are run at a much lower "priority" than when calling them bypassing the WCF interface.

Taking this into account, I am pretty sure this started sticking its head out after I decorated my main wcf class with the following, due to my UI thread locking up:

```
<ServiceBehavior(useSynchronizationContext:=False)>
```

Are the threads created due to the above decoration, running at a lower priority?

**Direct Call from form in WCF hosted App:** 5 seconds

**Call Through WCF Interface:** 20-30 seconds (Excluding time over the wire)

The physical return from the WCF service itself, once the internal functions are complete, is quite quick.

I do quite a lot of "work" once the internal functions are reached.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Basic WCF Service Code:

```
        Dim myservicehost As ServiceHost
        Dim myServiceAddress As New Uri("http://" & LocalIpAddress & ":" & tcp_port & "/" & servicename)

        myservicehost = New ServiceHost(GetType(myWCFFunctions), myServiceAddress)

        ' Enable metadata publishing.

        Dim smb As New ServiceMetadataBehavior()
        smb.HttpGetEnabled = True
        smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15
        myservicehost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb)


        myservicehost.Open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get this solved, and reverted back to my previous implementation.